# Load and save shiny inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a big shiny app with about 60 different inputs and it's still growing. Since I use this program a lot, I wanted the settings to be stored until next time I run the app. I made a csv-file that looks something like this:

```
input,value
input_a,10
input_b,#FFF000
input_c,hide
input_d,65400
```

I load the csv-file in ui.R and server.R with (not sure why I have to load it two times...)

```
config <- data.frame(lapply(read.csv(".//config.csv"), as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and have inputs like this

```
sliderInput(
"input_a",
"Number of cats:",
min = 1,max = 50,
value = config[config$input %in% "input_a", "value"]
)
```

In server.R, I let input changes replace the value in the table and also save the table to the file

```
observe({
config[config$input %in% "input_a", "value"] <- input$input_a
config[config$input %in% "input_b", "value"] <- input$input_b
config[config$input %in% "input_c", "value"] <- input$input_c
config[config$input %in% "input_d", "value"] <- input$input_d

write.table(config, file = ".//config.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
})
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, I searched and checked the other similar questions, I started with dget and dput, but then decided to have all relevant settings in one simple file. Sorry if I missed the most relevant question when I searched.

What I don't like about this is that the program also saves the table when it loads the program, before I make any input changes.

How can I get rid of that unnecessary save every time I run the program?
I don't understand all the "reactivity" in shiny, it's still a bit to complicated for me, I don't really know anything about R or programming, just trying to optimize my program since it gets slower with every new "feature" I add.

Comment: Better get used to the reactivity if you are going to be writing in Shiny. No way around it, and the sooner you get it, the less pain you will have. I suggest reading the docs a few times and writing very small programs to play with to see how it works.

Comment: Do you know about this? https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with keeping settings like that, but there might be a better way, and in anycase I would wrap it in a function like I did here.

And here is how you implement writing only "on exit" though (also please note the `session` parameter which is often not used):

```
library(shiny)
settingsdf <- data.frame(input=c("input_a","input_b","input_c"),
                         value=c(10,"#FF000","hide"),
                         stringsAsFactors=F)
setSetting <- function(pname,pval){
  idx <- which(settingsdf$input==pname)
  if (length(idx)==1){
    print(pval)
    settingsdf[ idx,2] <<- pval
  }
}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("region", "Region:", choices = colnames(WorldPhones)),
    plotOutput("phonePlot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
      if (length(input$region)>0){
        setSetting("input_a",input$region)
        barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
                ylab = "Number of Telephones", xlab = "Year")
      }
    })
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      write.csv(settingsdf,"settings.csv")
    })
  },
  options = list(height = 500)
)
```

Note that I am compressing the `ui.R` and `server.R` files into a single file which is not normally done but is nicer for these little examples.

This is not perfect code, I don't read the settings in and initialize the variables, and I use the `<<-` operator, which some people frown on. But it should help you along.

### Update

Here is a more complex version that loads and saves the parameters, and encapsulates them for use. It is better, although it probably should use S3 objects...

```
library(shiny)

# Settings code

settingsdf <- data.frame(input=c("input_a","region"),
                        value=c(10,"Asia"),stringsAsFactors=F)
setfname <- "settings.csv"

setSetting <- function(pname,pval){
  idx <- which(settingsdf$input==pname)
  if (length(idx)==1){
    settingsdf[ idx,"value"] <<- pval
  }
}
getSetting <- function(pname){
  idx <- which(settingsdf$input==pname)
  if (length(idx)==1){
    rv <- settingsdf[ idx,"value"]
    return(rv)
  } else {
    return("")
  }
}
readSettings <- function(){
  if (file.exists(setfname)){
    settingsdf <<- read.csv(setfname,stringsAsFactors=F)
  }
}
writeSettings <- function(){
  write.csv(settingsdf,setfname,row.names=F)
}

# ShinyApp

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("region","Region:", choices = colnames(WorldPhones)),
    plotOutput("phonePlot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    readSettings()
    vlastinput <- getSetting("region")
    if (vlastinput!=""){
        updateSelectInput(session, "region", selected = vlastinput )
    }
    output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
      if (length(input$region)>0){
        vlastinput <- input$region
        setSetting("region",vlastinput)
        barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
                ylab = "Number of Telephones", xlab = "Year")
      }
    })
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      writeSettings()
    })
  },
  options = list(height = 500)
)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

The save "on exit"  with the session object did the trick for my program without rewriting anything else. But I also like your exempels. I'm sure this will be useful for other newbies like me.


Almost feels like you get a bit spoiled how productive you can be with R and shiny even without a programming background.